# Rails basic form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new to Rails and web programming, and can't seem to accomplish this simple task. 
I have a post with several comments ( something like reddit or HN ). I want to add a new comment from the post view. The problem is that the comment is created by the create method of the Comment Controller, and it doesn't know what post it belongs to. Do I need to use a posts_helper to store the current post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on the rails guides site. It goes through creating a blog with comments.

You need to scope the creation of comments to the post that is being commented on. e.g. `@post.comments.create(params[:comment])`. The getting started guide will discuss all this.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing, but if I do @post.comments.create in the Post Controller, I lost the comment in the Comments Controller.  It seems to me that the Comment Controller is outside the scope of the Post Controller.

Comment: That's because the comments controller and the posts controller are totally separate. If you're creating the comments in the comments controller, then you will need to use the code above in the comments controller, not the posts controller. Read the guide, it will walk you through all of this.